# Setting the Cell = to a different Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet for refinancing.

First, the user will type in their original loan information and then click a Loan Setup Button, that performs a macro which will set up an amortization table by going from the `range("E" & k &":I" & k)`, where `k` is `B8` (the number of payments) so it only goes as far as however many payments there are.

Then, they can enter their new information (which payment it will start at, new payment amount, etc.) and hit a refinance button where it will calculate the new loan's amortization table.

As the user types in their information, underneath I have cells that will calculate things such as remaining balance, interest rate per period, etc. So in other words, without using a macro, just formulas that will calculate automatically.

**MY QUESTION IS**: Is there any way that I can set a cell value equal to another cell whose placement is determined by the Loan macro? When doing my macro, I was able to set the range from `("E" & k & "I:" & k)`, where I defined `k` as `B8`, which was the number of payments. Is there a way to do the same thing for a cell value, but without a macro, so that it displays automatically like a formula? (i.e. in cell B10, type = "B" & k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use INDEX() Function:

```
=INDEX(B:B,B8)
```